# Proving a matrix is positive definite via decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, positive-definite

Let $y,s \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be two vectors such that $y^\top s = 1$. To prove $$X = I + yy^\top - \frac{ss^\top}{s^\top s} $$
is a positive definite matrix, I found a source which shows:
$$X = \left( I + \frac{ys^\top}{\sqrt{s^\top s}} - \frac{ss^\top}{s^\top s} \right)  \left( I + \frac{ys^\top}{\sqrt{s^\top s}} - \frac{ss^\top}{s^\top s} \right) ^\top$$
hence $X \succ0$. How can I obtain this decomposition? I can, of course, reverse engineer the result, but I want to start from the first definition and decompose myself.

Edit: Ugly and meaningless reverse engineering:
$$\begin{align*}
    X^* &= I - \frac{1}{s^\top s} ss^\top + yy^\top \\
     & = I + \frac{s^\top y}{\sqrt{s^\top s}} - \frac{1}{s^\top s} ss^\top + yy^\top  -\frac{s^\top y}{\sqrt{s^\top s}} \\
     & = \left( I + \frac{s^\top y}{\sqrt{s^\top s}} - \frac{1}{s^\top s} ss^\top \right) + \left( \frac{ys^\top}{\sqrt{s^\top s}} + yy^\top - \frac{ys^\top}{\sqrt{s^\top s}} \right) - \left( \frac{ss^\top }{s^\top s} + \frac{sy^\top}{\sqrt{s^\top s}} - \frac{ss^\top}{s^\top s} \right) \\
     & = \left( I + \frac{s^\top y}{\sqrt{s^\top s}} - \frac{ss^\top}{s^\top s}  \right) + \left( \frac{ys^\top}{\sqrt{s^\top s}} + \frac{ys^\top s y^\top}{s^\top s} - \frac{ys^\top s s^\top}{s^\top s \sqrt{s^\top s}} \right) - \left( \frac{ss^\top }{s^\top s} + \frac{s s^\top s y^\top}{s^\top s \sqrt{s^\top s}} - \frac{s s^\top s s^\top}{s^\top s s^\top s} \right) \\
     & = \left( I + \frac{ys^\top}{\sqrt{s^\top s}} - \frac{ss^\top}{s^\top s} \right) \left( I + \frac{sy^\top}{\sqrt{s^\top s}} - \frac{ss^\top}{s^\top s}  \right) \\
     & = \left( I + \frac{ys^\top}{\sqrt{s^\top s}} - \frac{ss^\top}{s^\top s} \right) \left( I + \frac{ys^\top}{\sqrt{s^\top s}} - \frac{ss^\top}{s^\top s} \right)^\top.
\end{align*} $$

Comment: It can't be positive definite for all $y,s$. Take scalars , $y=0, s=1$, then $X=0$ which is not positive definite.

Comment: there is also a fact that $y^\top s  = 1 $ so sorry

Answer (score 2):

if you really want the decomposition, then I suppose this isn't the answer you want, but there is a simpler and very general approach.

Consider
$P:= I - \frac{\mathbf{ss}^T}{\mathbf s^T \mathbf s} \succeq 0$

you can in fact check that this is real symmetric and $P^2 = P$ so it is a projector and rank is given by its trace =$n-1$. (You can also do this with diagonalization of a symmetric rank one matrix and then shift all eigenvalues by one).  So for any $\big\Vert \mathbf v\big \Vert_2 = 1$, we have
$\mathbf v^T P\mathbf v \geq 0$  with equality *iff* $\mathbf v \propto \mathbf s$

now consider $X = P + \mathbf {yy}^T$
for any unit length $\mathbf v\in \mathbb R^n$,
$\mathbf v^T X \mathbf v = \mathbf v^T P \mathbf v + \mathbf v^T \mathbf{yy}^T \mathbf v \gt 0$

and so $X \succ 0$
i.e. if $\mathbf v \propto \mathbf s$ then this reads as $0+1\gt 0$
and otherwise this reads $\alpha + \gamma\gt 0$ where $\alpha \gt 0$ and $\gamma \geq 0$

*underlying idea:*
the addition of a positive semidefinite matrix and a positive definite matrix gives a positive definite matrix.  This idea turns out to be useful in many different areas and is rather simple unlike some decompositions.

Comment: I think this is nicer than the decomposition approach!

Comment: @independentvariable here's likely where the decomposition came from -- assume $\big \Vert s \big \Vert_2 := 1$ to simplify symbol manipulation.  They observe that  $I  - ss^T$  has $s$ its 1 dim nullspace.  Since $y$ is not orthogonal to (and is rescaled to dotproduct 1 w/) $s$ if we 'increment' to 'push' $s$ out of the kernel, we have $B:=I  - ss^T + sy^T$ then $Bs =s \neq \mathbf 0$  and $\det(B) = \det\big( (I + sy^T) - ss^T\big)= \det(I + sy^T)\cdot\big(1  - s^T(I + sy^T)^{-1}s\big) = 2\cdot(1-\frac{1}{2})=1$ (determinant rank 1 update formula).  $B$ is invertible $\to$ $B^TB = X\succ 0$.